# Apply a comparison between two numpy.arrays to only one column but retrieve whole rows

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays with two columns each.

```
import numpy as np


a = np.array([[1131, 1],
              [4131, 2],
              [421,  1],
              [41,   1]])

b = np.array([[5881, 2],
              [637,  2],
              [742,  2],
              [36,   2]])
```

and I want to create a third array with 2 columns that the fist column will contain the minimum between the first columns of a and b and the second column will contain whatever the second column of the array containing the minimum had.

the third array should be

```
c = np.array([[1131, 1],
              [637,  2],
              [421,  1],
              [36,   2]])
```

How can I do that efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a perfect case to *ab-use* [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) within [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) -

```
np.where((a[:,0] < b[:,0])[:,None],a,b)
```

The beauty is that it would work independent of the number of columns in `a` and `b`, as that's where the broadcasting helps out.

Sample run -

```
In [78]: a
Out[78]: 
array([[1131,   99],
       [4131,    4],
       [ 421,   56],
       [  41,   78]])

In [79]: b
Out[79]: 
array([[5881,   23],
       [ 637,   42],
       [ 742, 7882],
       [  36,   62]])

In [80]: np.where((a[:,0] < b[:,0])[:,None],a,b)
Out[80]: 
array([[1131,   99],
       [ 637,   42],
       [ 421,   56],
       [  36,   62]])
```

Comment: that was exactly the kind of answer I was aiming for

Answer (score 1):

You can use [masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html#operations-on-masks):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1131, 1],
...               [4131, 2],
...               [421,  1],
...               [41,   1]])
>>> b = np.array([[5881, 2],
...               [637,  2],
...               [742,  2],
...               [36,   2]])
>>> mask_b = a[:, 0] < b[:, 0]
>>> mask_b
array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> mask_a = a[:, 0] > b[:, 0]
>>> mask_a
array([False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> masked_a = np.ma.masked_array(a, mask=np.array([mask_a, mask_a]).T, fill_value=0)
>>> masked_a
masked_array(data =
 [[1131 1]
 [-- --]
 [421 1]
 [-- --]],
             mask =
 [[False False]
 [ True  True]
 [False False]
 [ True  True]],
       fill_value = 0)

>>> masked_b = np.ma.masked_array(b, mask=np.array([mask_b, mask_b]).T, fill_value=0)
>>> masked_b
masked_array(data =
 [[-- --]
 [637 2]
 [-- --]
 [36 2]],
             mask =
 [[ True  True]
 [False False]
 [ True  True]
 [False False]],
       fill_value = 0)

>>> masked_a.filled() + masked_b.filled()
array([[1131,    1],
       [ 637,    2],
       [ 421,    1],
       [  36,    2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for that to get indices for `a` and `b`. Then create `c` as [`zeros_like`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjOq9rN-p_MAhWsKJoKHQdjCUgQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.scipy.org%2Fdoc%2Fnumpy-1.10.1%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.zeros_like.html&usg=AFQjCNF90J0-rGM35RIZz9AMxK1RBoYP7Q&sig2=SMPyNoL7kW0EC4OD-AypMw&bvm=bv.119745492,d.bGs) `a` and fill it with `a` and `b` according to indices:

```
idx_a = np.where(a[:,0] <  b[:, 0])
idx_b = np.where(a[:,0] >  b[:, 0])
c = np.zeros_like(a)
c[idx_a] = a[idx_a]
c[idx_b] = b[idx_b]

In [43]: c
Out[43]:
array([[1131,    1],
       [ 637,    2],
       [ 421,    1],
       [  36,    2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness purposes here is another solution:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([[1131, 1],
                 [4131, 2],
                 [421,  1],
                 [41,   1]])

b = numpy.array([[5881, 2],
                 [637,  2],
                 [742,  2],
                 [36,   2]])

c1 = np.amin(np.hstack((a[:,0][:,np.newaxis],b[:,0][:,np.newaxis])),axis=1)
c2 = np.array([a[i,1] if a[i,0]<b[i,0] else b[i,1] for i in range(a.shape[0])])
c = np.hstack((c1[:,np.newaxis],c2[:,np.newaxis]))
print(c)
```

, results in:

```
[[1131    1]
 [ 637    2]
 [ 421    1]
 [  36    2]]
```

Really liked @Divakar solution though (+1).